# to throw something on someone

Tags: verbs

What is the perfect verb for 'throwing notes' on someone as a sign of appraisal?

Is this 'throw' or 'shower'?

The act can be seen in this picture, although it's not much clear.

Can we say: They are showering currency notes on the man.

[image: ver]

Answer (score 1):

"They are showering him with money"  works well.

You can say "with banknotes" or specify a particular amount: "with £20 notes" or "$100 bills" (or ₹100 banknotes etc) but not "with currency notes"